# How to specify the remote IP dynamically when send HTTP(s) requests using net/http package

Tags: go

**Requirement**: worker goroutines concurrently send HTTPS(S) requests to various IPs. The URL and server IP are specified by the "main" routine in the parameter list when creating workers.
**For instance**: there are 100 worker goroutines requests https://www.google.com/ from different server IPs. The first worker asks for it from 1.1.1.1, and the second one does exactly the same thing but a different server IP (say 2.2.2.2).
**Current solution**: assign one http.Client with customized dial function in http.Transport for each routine.

```
   go func(host, url string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        Client:=&http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
                n, e := net.Dial("tcp", host)
                fmt.Println(e)
                return n, e
            },
          },
       }

        resp, err := Client.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()

        c, e := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if e != nil {
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(string(c))

    }(realHost, url)
```

according to the godoc, Clients and Transports are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and for efficiency should only be created once and re-used.

**Questions**: So how can I fulfill my requirement by re-using the Client and transport?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a request and swap hosts in the request.

```
req, err := http.NewRequst(“GET”, url, nil)
req.Host = req.URL.Host // set host header
req.URL.Host = host     // set dial host
```

Use the default client and transport to execute the request.

```
 resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

Comment: Thanks, but 1) why do you do req.Host = req.URL.Host? I guess req.Host always equals to req.URL.Host by default. What makes them different?   2) I don't think this solution works with HTTPS, it fails to check SSL cert (certificate name does not match input).

Comment: (1) the host header is different  from the dial address. (2) Yeah, this only works with http.